# Clips that hold plug wires onto coil pack?

Tags: saturn, ignition

On my 1999 Saturn SL2, there are clips that are supposed to hold the ignition/plug wires in place onto the coil pack and the bolt that goes through it may play a role in grounding the circuit.  One of them is missing.  There's corrosion on the pack where it's missing, so it's apparently important.  What is that part called, and can you buy replacements anywhere?

Comment: Can you post a picture of the offending part? That may make IDing it easier.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say check at a dealership parts counter, except that Saturn dealers don't exist anymore.  I thought I heard something about Saturn having their own parts system separate from what all the other GM divisions used, but I can't find anything to confirm/deny that at the moment.  You could try the parts counter at a Cadillac/Chevy/Buick/GMC dealer.  Taking some donuts wouldn't hurt.  If you're lucky they can ID the part and possibly even order it if there are any to be had.  If nothing else, maybe they can get you a part number you can use to find what you need from a vendor of [NOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_old_stock) parts.

Answer (score 1):

Best answer is a GM parts counter as @Mark answered.  Depending on the exact design/configuration you may be able to secure it with a ziptie.  I broke the clip for the power transistor plug on my Mitsubishi, but was able to thread a ziptie through it to keep it secure.